# Least number of days required to finish watching all movies given durations array if you can watch maximum 3.00 duration movie per day

Tags: algorithm, recursion, data-structures, dynamic-programming

> Input:  double array representing duration of movies e.g.
> `durations[] ={1.01, 2.4, 1.01, 1.01, 1.4}`. You can watch maximum
> 3.00 duration movie per day.
> Find the least number of days needed to finish watching all the movies.
> Constraint: 1.01 <= duration[i]
> <= 3.00.
> (You can choose to watch any movie on a day and won't repeat
> watching a movie)
>
> Sample Test Cases:
> Input:  duration[] = {1.01, 2.4, 1.01, 1.01,
> 1.4} Output: 3
> Input: duration[] = {1.01, 2.4, 1.4, 1.6, 2.6, 1.7} Output: 4
> Input: duration[] = {1.01, 2.4, 1.5, 1.6, 2.6, 1.7} Output: 5

I got this in a placement coding test and couldn't finish it on time
but did it later using recursion. It worked with few test cases I
custom made but I'm not not sure if it will work for all possible
test cases. Also I feel it could be enhanced for better time
complexity. Kindly help.

My insight: You would be able to watch max 2 movies a day as
durations are always >= 1.01 so watching any 3 movies would make
duration exceed 3.00.

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class MoviesBetterSolution {

      public static void main(String[] args) {

           double arr[] = {2.0,1.01,1.4,2.4,1.71};  //test case

           System.out.println( f( 0, 0.00 , 1, 3.00,  new ArrayList<Integer>(),  arr , 0) ); 
           //days passed a 1 as we start from day 1
           //initial wtn (watched till now for a particular day) passes is 0.00

    }   static int minDays = Integer.MAX_VALUE;

    //wtn -> watched till now (keeps track of duration of movies watched on the current day
    //taken keeps track of number of movies watched on current day
    // picked : watched movies on the day till now  private static int f(int i, double wtn, int days, double limit,  ArrayList<Integer>
picked, double[] arr, int taken) {

          //updating minDays after reaching a point where all movies have been watched

            if(picked.size()==arr.length) {
                   if( days<minDays ) minDays = days;
                   return minDays;  
            }
           if(i == arr.length) {  //finished traversing array
             if(taken != 0) {     //restart traversing to watch unwatched movies only if atleast 1 
                       //movie was watched on the day, setting taken for the new traversal to be 0
                      i = 0;         
                      taken = 0;            }else {       // otherwise just return if nothing was watched on the day, otherwise it 
                              //will stackoverflow for all non watch choice recursion branch
                        return minDays;`            }       }
                if((wtn + arr[i] <= limit) && !(picked.contains(i)) ) {  //only movies that havent been watched can be watched
            
               ArrayList<Integer> temp = new ArrayList<Integer>();
               temp = (ArrayList<Integer>) picked.clone();
               temp.add(i);
               if(taken<2) { //as u can watch only 2 movies a day
                   f(i+1, wtn + arr[i] , days, limit, temp, arr, taken+1);  //watch & move to next movie but on same day            }
                        f(0, 0 , days +1 , limit, temp, arr, taken+1);  // watch & move to next movie but on next day , wtn and index(i) set to 0 as u
starting new day        }
     
             f(i+1, wtn, days, limit, picked, arr, taken); //not watch & move to next movie on same day

              return minDays;   } }
```

Comment: This looks like [Leet Code #2589](https://leetcode.com/problems/minimum-time-to-complete-all-tasks/description/).

Answer (score 2):

Assuming all movies have run times between 1.01 and 3.00, solve this in O(n log n)

```
1. sort your list
2. set days = 0
3. set two pointers to the two ends of your list.
4. repeatedly do the following until all elements have been processed:
4.1 increment days
4.2 if the sum of the movies referred to is <= 3.0 then move both pointers towards the center, otherwise just decrement the larger one.
```

Just before the end, it's possible that both pointers refer to the same element. That takes a day.

Comment: Save yourself some work by preprocessing with a step 0. All movies > 1.99 will take an entire day by themselves. Remove them from your list in O(n) and in (2) set days equal to the number removed.

Answer (score 0):

I also got the same question in an interview but could not able to solve at that time..
My solution through iterative approach is..find max sum pair of movies to get min days.
1.intialise two pointers(i,j) with for loops as at Max we can pick 2 movies.
2.get max sum of two movies and less than 3 condition and block input array indices by filling with -1 ..so that we can skip that element as it already picked.
3.if no pair formed then block only 1 movie with -1 ,ie.ith index.
4.at end of second for loop increment day counter and return days at end of loops.

Let me know if there are any issues with this approach and any better solutions is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I got this one in an interview, heres how I solved it.

```
//Move list to an array, sort the array (baseline O(nlogn))
//set two int index pointers, left to the first element right to the last, and an index solution counter
//while left != right
    //if arr[left] + arr[right] <= 3.00
        //increment solution counter
        //push left ptr right and right left
    //else
        //increment solution counter
        //push right ptr left
//check if left == right, inc counter if so
//return counter
```

Solved simply in O(nlogn) time.